# Precise statement of Legendre's theorem on spherical triangles

Tags: spherical-trigonometry

[This Google Books search](http://books.google.com/books?id=KqlXAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PR5&dq=legendre+theorem+spherical+excess+area+triangle&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bAsqUoH7DMSbygHXzIC4AQ&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=legendre%20theorem%20spherical%20excess%20area%20triangle&f=false) finds a page that says this:

> **74. Legendre's theorem**
>   ${}\qquad\qquad{}$ *If each of the angles of a spherical triangle whose*
>   *sides are small when compared with the radius of the sphere*
>   *be diminished by one third of the spherical excess, the triangle*
>   *may be solved as a plane triangle whose sides are equal to*
>   *the sides of the spherical triangle, and whose angles are these*
>   *reduced angles.*

"Spherical excess" I take to mean the amount by which the sum of the three angles exceeds a half-circle.

Similarly imprecise statements are found by additional googling.  The sides are "small when compared to", etc., and the solution is approximate.  So I'm thinking there should be something maybe with a Landau little-o, saying as the size goes to $0$, the error goes to $0$ like some power of the size.  Maybe.

Does anyone know of a mathematically precise statement of this proposition?

Comment: Your help is appreciated.  But I've altered it further since then.

Comment: That last change looks much better! Software was outwitted in the end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a paper about Legendre's theorem by Zbyněk Nádeník, *[Legendre theorem on spherical triangles](http://www.vugtk.cz/odis/sborniky/sb2005/Sbornik_50_let_VUGTK/Part_1-Scientific_Contribution/2-Nadenik.pdf)*. The paper states and proves several versions of the theorem (with different error terms).

As I understand, here is what Legendre originally proved (see also [Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0_%28%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%29) for historical references):

**Theorem [Legendre, stated in 1787, proved in 1798].** Consider a spherical triangle with sides $a$, $b$, and $c$ and angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$. Then the plane triangle with sides $a$, $b$, and $c$ has angles $\alpha'$, $\beta'$ and $\gamma'$:

\begin{align*}
\alpha' &= \alpha - \varepsilon/3 + O(\varepsilon \cdot M^2),\\
\beta'  &= \beta - \varepsilon/3 + O(\varepsilon \cdot M^2),\\
\gamma' &= \gamma - \varepsilon/3 + O(\varepsilon \cdot M^2),
\end{align*}
where $\varepsilon = \alpha + \beta + \gamma - \pi$, $M = \max(a,b,c)/R$, and $R$ is the radius of the sphere. Note that $\varepsilon = O(M^2)$.